# ¿Quisiera entender que devuelve cada parte de la línea de código?¿Cómo recibe e interpreta la matriz Data a start luego de pasar por for?

Tags: array, bucle-for, numpy, machine-learning

> **Data es <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (4,1)  [[-1.38695219]   [0.54272042]   [-0.42211588]   [1.26634765]]**
>
> **Obs = 2**

`X = np.atleast_3d(np.array([Data[start:start + Obs] for start in range(0, Data.shape[0] - Obs)]))`

`print(X)`

> **[[[-1.38695219]    [ 0.54272042]]   [[ 0.54272042]   [-0.42211588]]]**

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: `[Data[start:start + Obs] for start in range(0, Data.shape[0] - Obs)]` es lo que se conoce como "list comprehension": https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions